# Cloning a Guardian Edge Protected Drive

Tags: cloning, symantec

I need to clone/ghost a GE protected hard drive, but I am running into various issues. Norton Ghost seems to just freeze up, XXClone puts up strange errors.  I realize the entire drive is encrypted, but would that make a difference to a cloning software?

Anybody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux you can use the `dd` command to clone data from one drive to another.

If you don't have a machine running Linux, you can download a bootable CD from e.g. http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page which will have `dd` and other useful commands for dealing with hard drives and data recovery.